# Angular4 multiple Material autocomplete causes page to freeze

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

I am trying to implement a form with 9 fields with dropdown and autocomplete using the Material Autocomplete module in Angular4.

I made it work for 8 of them, but whenever I try to add the ninth, the page freezes and no error pops up in the console.

I edited the code to remove async from everywhere thinking that might be the problem, but the situation stays the same.

I also tried creating a new component and copy/pasting everything (but using a dummy data source), and it works fine.

Edit: I created a plunker with the version which works. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/y7pi6N4Yvng86dMzXfUz?p=preview

```
   <div>
      <md-input-container class="doc-name">
        <input mdInput (ngModelChange)="applyFilter($event,5)" placeholder="Name: " [mdAutocomplete]="auto1" [formControl]="filtersForm.controls[5]">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-autocomplete #auto1="mdAutocomplete">
        <md-option *ngFor="let type of filteredFilters[5]" [value]="type">
          {{ type }}
        </md-option>
      </md-autocomplete>
    </div>
```

I expect the page is too heavy on code and that makes the browsers block. Is there a limit for the memory usage? And if that's the case, do you have any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the template code?

Comment: The code for the not working file is very big and I cannot disclose it. :(

Comment: You might use too many bindings  and form validators. Without seeing the file we cannot say.